# Como pegar o text de um radio button?

Tags: php, javascript

Em meu código eu verifico o radio selecionado e gostaria de pegar o campo text do radio também. Como deveria fazer?!

No while ele monta os radios conforme os valores encontrados na tabela e mostra o     nome dos campos encontrados.

```
<?
    while($w_registro = pg_fetch_object($w_queryresultado))
      {                                   
      print('<input type="radio" name="rb_peri" id="id_rb_peri" value="'.$seq_cara.'">');
      print($tx_desc);
      }
?>
```

Ai quando o radio for selecionado e emitido um "GO", ele chama a função para verificar o radio selecionado.

```
function radio(){
    w_qtde_rb = document.forms['sai_frm_alte_novo_cara'].rb_peri.length;

    for  (w_i=0; w_i < w_qtde_rb; w_i++)
        {           
         if(document.forms['sai_frm_alte_novo_cara'].rb_peri[w_i].checked == true)
            {   
            get_valor= document.forms['sai_frm_alte_novo_cara'].rb_peri[w_i].value;
            }     
        }
}
```

Ai eu gostaria de pegar o nome do campo referente ao radio selecionado. Alguma ideia?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Se você fizer uma pequena alteração no seu PHP, para que o texto do radiobutton seja impresso dentro de uma tag (por exemplo: `<label>`, que por sinal é uma boa, em termos de usabilidade), basta adicionar ao seu JavaScript a linha destacada:

```
function radio(){
    w_qtde_rb = document.forms['sai_frm_alte_novo_cara'].rb_peri.length;

    for  (w_i=0; w_i < w_qtde_rb; w_i++)
    {           
        if(document.forms['sai_frm_alte_novo_cara'].rb_peri[w_i].checked == true)
        {   
            get_valor = document.forms['sai_frm_alte_novo_cara'].rb_peri[w_i].value;

            // Adicionar esta linha:
            get_texto = document.forms['sai_frm_alte_novo_cara'].rb_peri[w_i].nextSibling.innerHTML;
        }     
    }
}
```

A modificação correspondente, no PHP, deve ser a substituição da linha

```
print($tx_desc);
```

por

```
print('<label for="id_rb_peri">' . $tx_desc . '</label>');
```

Comment: Muito obrigado @RuiPimentel me ajudou muito!!!

Answer (score -2):

se você preferir usar JavaScript pode fazer assim:
$("#id_rb_peri").val(); ai você vai ter o valor dela e pode fazer o que quiser !