# Duvida em função .length

Tags: php, javascript

No meu caso eu estou eu estou pegando quantos registros estão dentro da variável. Mas a função `.length` determina que quando só existe um registro ele é `undefined`, sendo que devia mostrar que existe um registro nela. Isso é algum erro da própria função ou existe uma maneira de arrumar? Ou existe algum outro método que eu posso utilizar?

Estou armazenando assim:

```
function insert_info(){
    w_qtde_info = document.forms['my_form'].blc_info.length;

}

    <form name="my_form"  method="post">
    <table width="100%">
    <tr>
    <td>
<?php
        while($w_cont <= $w_opc)
        { 
        print('<input type="radio" name="blc_info" value="">');
         } 
        print('<input type="button" onClick="insert_info();" value=">>">');
?>
    </td>
    </tr>
    </table>
    </form>
```

**w_opc** é determinado pelo usuário .. Ou seja, vai acrescentar os radios (conforme o exmplo) conforme o valor que o usuário determinou!

**Obs:** peguei a parte de php como referencia de : [Text radio](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/31227/como-pegar-o-text-de-um-radio-button)

Comment: eu gostaria de ver o corpo do seu form.... tem como voce postar?

Comment: O que é `blc_info`? um campo input?

Comment: Sim, blc_info é um input!

Comment: `length` nesse caso não esta a ser usado como função, mas sim como propriedade. Também não encontrei nada [na especificação](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element.length) sobre esse comportamento que descreves. Esse `length` aí é nativo mesmo ou é algo que alguém da sua equipe implementou?

Comment: @Renan ele é nativo mesmo! Pois acabei testando com outros itens (radio com valores determinados) e ele ocorre o mesmo erro!

Comment: Testei aqui no Chrome e essa propriedade sempre dá undefined para inputs e textareas. Você fala em "registros dentro de uma variável" - por acaso esses registros são propriedades que você está inserindo em no input? Se tiver mais código que mexa nesse input, edita a pergunta pra incluir isso, ok?

Comment: Bruno, então o que quer é o `value` dele não? tipo `w_qtde_info = document.forms['my_form'].blc_info.value;`

Comment: Não @Sergio, eu preciso saber quantos registros foram "incluidos" dentro da variável! Vou postar um exemplo com radio que acho que fica mais fácil!

Comment: Bruno, esse `while` é PHP?

Comment: @Sergio, Sim (editei meio rápido)!

Comment: Nesse caso o seu javascript está correto, o que tem é erros no PHP. Falta um `echo` antes do HTML e falta abrir e fechar o PHP... sabe como fazer? outra questão é a sua função não retornar nada. Ela está completa?

Comment: Sim @Sergio ela está completa. Faltou a abertura do PHP porque acabei editando rápido e acabei esquecendo de colocado aqui!

Comment: Bruno, essa sua função não faz nada. Ou seja, não responde nada. O que quer fazer com o numero que essa variável tem? Pelo menos um `alert(w_qtde_info);` dentro da função?

Answer (score 1):

Por que você não faz isso?

```
   function insert_info(){
        w_qtde_info = document.forms['my_form'].blc_info.length || [];
    }
```

Com isso se a sua consulta retornar undefined você não quebrará uma consulta em `w_qtde_info.length`

Comment: Mas @felipekm, é que se caso só exista um registro dentro da variável, ele deve mostrar que existe esse único registro!

Comment: Não compreendo, o que retorna esse objeto?
document.forms['my_form'].blc_info

Comment: O document.forms['my_form'].blc_info.length retorna quantos registros contém em blc_info!

Comment: Sim, entendi isso, porém, Vc diz: "Mas a função .length determina que quando só existe um registro ele é undefined", isso não é verdade, LENGTH jamais retornará undefined. O único erro que vc pode encontrar ali é 'document.forms['my_form'].blc_info' ser undefined, por isso sugeri a resposta assim.

Comment: Nesse caso está dizendo que o document.forms['my_form'].blc_info não está pegando os valores do form ?

Comment: Provavelmente, com essa validação acima vc elimina a possibilidade de "estourar" sua app ao consultar a property Length desse Array. Boa Sorte